# htaccess wordpresses accessing files in sub directory without 404

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've set up Wordpress in the root directory on a server for a client. They previously had an old version of Wordpress installed before and whatever way the htaccess was set up it allowed them to view sub directories of files in the FTP without getting a wordpress 404 page.

I managed to get it working by turning off RewriteEngine, but all of the links broken on the website.

This is the htaccess at the moment:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Why didn't you take a backup of the old site before you touched anything on their server?

Comment: I did back it up, but I can't understand why it was working.

Comment: Most of Wordpresses rewrite rules are stored in the database, not the htaccess. You could use a plugin like Rewrite Rules Inspector to see what rewrites are set up.